# how can i extract this array php or Cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x and i am sending data from android to my webapp in a json fromat

i am getting the data in my **$data** variable when i **print_r** the data

```
  Array (
     [sms] => [[+16063934284, hello, 1, 1372671157000]]
  )
```

i want to access each element of this array or want to save each element in a seperate variable.. for example i want to do something like this

```
   $number = ['sms'][0]
```

sorry i am week in arrays so dont how can i do this

Comment: most likely you are both submitting your data wrong, and not parsing it correctly - the Array-thing in the question is (probably, hard to tell as there are no quotes) a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json data inside `$data['sms']` is not correct json. You need to manually parse this string or generate correct json in your Android app.
If you want to parse your data use next code:

```
$sms = str_replace('[[', '', $data['sms']);
$sms = str_replace(']]', '', $sms);
$sms = explode(', ', $sms);
print_r($sms);
```

As you can see in output $sms is an array with all your attributes.

Comment: am getting data in json .. when i decode the data then i get the following result which i have in my question .should i have to decode again

Comment: can i do this foreach($data as $value) {
    print $value . "\n";
} ?

Comment: you have array of arrays. `$data[0]` is array. You can just set `$data = $data[0]` and then use `foreach($data as $value)`

Comment: what i have done right now is i did this                                             $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 $data = json_decode($data['sms']);  pr($data) it prints only this "<pre></pre>"

Comment: Because it's not correct json. You can generate correct json in your Android app or just use my solution. I have updated my answer. Check it.

Comment: so now i am doing this ? is that correct ? this is what u r saying i should try    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

            $sms = str_replace('[[', '', $data['sms']);
            $sms = str_replace(']]', '', $sms);
            $sms = explode(', ', $sms);
            print_r($sms);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32678/discussion-between-michael-sivolobov-and-hellosheikh)

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JSON, if your response is something like this:

> [sms] => [[ '+16063934284', 'hello', 1, 1372671157000 ]]

Now you can use `json_decode` functon, so then you will have the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16063934284
            [1] => 123
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1372671157000
        )

)
```

So later, you can use `foreach()` to iterate through the elements of the new array.

Here is a working example:

Comment: i am getting data in json .. when i decode the data then i get the following result which i have in my question ...

Comment: Array (
     [sms] => [[+16063934284, hello, 1, 1372671157000]]
  )

Comment: Well, what is the output from: print_r( json_decode( $data['sms'] ) );

Comment: what i have done right now is i did this $data = json_decode($json, TRUE); $data = json_decode($data['sms']); pr($data) it prints only this "<pre></pre>"

Comment: I think you get this error, because your JSON is not well-formatted. You can test your JSON here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know how you’re structuring data, but you should be able to assign it to a list like this:

```
foreach ($data['sms'] as $row) {
    list($number, $message, $param3, $param4) = $row;
}
```

But for some reason you seem to have an array in an array (with the two opening square brackets) so it would actually look like this:

```
foreach ($data['sms'] as $row) {
    list($number, $message, $param3, $param4) = $row[0];
}
```

Either way, you can then just access the number in the loop via the variable name:

```
foreach ($data['sms'] as $row) {
    list($number, $message, $param3, $param4) = $row[0];
    printf('Number is %s', $number);
}
```

Comment: That’s because you weren’t suppose to use it verbatim. I don’t know what format your data’s coming from your Android app in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **explode()** function, to separate the values in array.

```
explode(Array_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send proper JSON from the app, you can simply use `$array = json_decode($data['sms'])`
The correct JSON string would look like `[["+16063934284", "hello", 1, 1372671157000]]`
Note that the " instead of ' (quote vs apostrophe) is important to JSON formatting, sorry Kristian Vitozev. Also note that using explode on ', ' will break if the SMS message contains a comma.

Here is a code example:

```
$sms_list = json_decode($data['sms']);
foreach($sms_list as $sms){
    list($phone_number, $message, $unknown_bool, $timestamp) = $sms;
    //...
}
```